# Proving $A \rightarrow B \therefore \neg A \lor B$

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

In forall x: Calgary, by P. D. Magnus, section 16 p.154, D. 3, appears this exercise (Fitch-style natural deduction):

[image]

I am trying to derive a contradiction on line 4. Is this approach correct? How can I continue ?

Comment: $\neg A$ is not a logical consequence of $A\to B$, so I don't see how there could possibly be a justification that would lead to line 6 in any proof.

Comment: $A\rightarrow B \Rightarrow$ If $\texttt{NOT} B$ then $\texttt{NOT} A$.

Comment: @mjw, at this stage in the book, I cannot use logical equivalences or implications.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*

Assume $A$ **and** $\lnot (\lnot A \lor B)$.

With $A$ derive a contradiction and from it $\lnot A$.

Then, use it for a new contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I should assume $A \land \lnot (\lnot A \lor B)$ on the same line ?

Comment: No. @F.Zer . First assume $\neg(\neg A\vee B)$, and then place your proof inside that context - so you have something to contradict.$$\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{~~A\to B}{\fitch{\neg(\neg A\vee B)}{\fitch{~~A}{~~B\\~~~\vdots\\~~\bot}\\\neg A\\\neg A\vee B\\~~~\vdots}\\~~~\vdots\\\neg A\vee B}$$

Comment: Thank you ! How did you learn to do such an awesome proof in MathJax ? Could you give me a link or pointer ?

Comment: I followed your suggestion and came up with this proof. Do you think this proof is correct ? Do I used IP rule correctly ?

$$
\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{A \to B}{
  \fitch{\neg(\neg A \vee B)}{
    \fitch{A}{
      B \\
      \neg A \vee B \\
      \bot
    } \\
    \neg A \\
    \neg A \vee B \\
    \bot
  } \\
  \neg A \vee B
}
$$

Comment: @F.Zer - Exactly !

Answer (score 0):

The text says that all of the exercises require the IP strategy.  To review, the IP strategy means that when you want to prove a formula *F*, you need to assume the negation of that formula.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\lnot A\lor A$ is true. By the hypothesis, whenever $A$ is true then $B$ is true. Therefore, $\lnot A\lor B$ is true.